# Gallery of SWF files in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, flash, gallery

Is there a way to show a gallery of swf files in a Wordpress post instead of pictures? I need to create a gallery of flash animations in each post and I can't figure out how to go about it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use flash then I would go with [Slideshow Pro Director](http://slideshowpro.net/news/archive/2010/12/slideshowpro-director-plugin-for-wordpress-now-available.php/) The WordPress plugin is free but you need a Slideshow Pro license which is only like $30.  I like it because it can dynamically pull images via xml from a folder.

Comment: Chris thanks for your response. Unfortunately, Slideshow Pro Director isn't what I'm looking for. I don't want to display a gallery of images. Rather I want to create a gallery of swf files.

Comment: Can anyone else suggest something? Please.